# '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'entryconfigure'

Tags: python, tkinter, menu, attributes

I have a notepad.
So In the notepad there is a bar called 'bar'.
in this bar there is a view cascade menu called 'view'.
in this view menu there is a language cascade menu called 'language'.
in this language cascade menu there are 3 commands for "English","Portuguese" and "Spanish".

each command executes a def, each one with their respective arguments.

```
def lang(l):
    global lan

    if l=="English":
        if lan!='English':
            janela.title('Notepad')
            file.entryconfigure('Abrir', label='Open')
            file.entryconfigure('Salvar', label='Save')
            file.entryconfigure('Salvar como', label='Save as')
            view.entryconfigure('Idioma', label='Language')
            help.entryconfigure('Sobre...', label='About...')

            if lan=='Português':
                bar.entryconfigure('Arquivo', label='File')
                bar.entryconfigure('Exibir', label='View')
                bar.entryconfigure('Ajuda', label='Help')
                file.entryconfigure('Novo', label='New')
                file.entryconfigure('Abrir Recente', label='Open Recent')
                file.entryconfigure('Sair', label='Quit')
                view.entryconfigure('Mostrar nome do arquivo', label='Show file name')

            if lan=='Español':
                bar.entryconfigure('Archivo', label='File')
                bar.entryconfigure('Vista', label='View')
                bar.entryconfigure('Ayuda', label='Help')
                file.entryconfigure('Nuevo', label='New')
                file.entryconfigure('Abrir Reciente', label='Open Recent')
                file.entryconfigure('Salir', label='Quit')
                view.entryconfigure('Mostrar nombre de archivo', label='Show file name')

            lan="English"
            titleshow(s=False)
    if l=="Português":
        if lan!='Português':
            janela.title('Bloco de Notas')

            if lan=='English':
                bar.entryconfigure('File', label='Arquivo')
                bar.entryconfigure('View', label='Exibir')
                bar.entryconfigure('Help', label='Ajuda')
                file.entryconfigure('New', label='Novo')
                file.entryconfigure('Open', label='Abrir')
                file.entryconfigure('Open Recent', label='Abrir Recente')
                file.entryconfigure('Save', label='Salvar')
                file.entryconfigure('Save as', label='Salvar como')
                file.entryconfigure('Quit', label='Sair')
                view.entryconfigure('Language', label='Idioma')
                help.entryconfigure('About...', label='Sobre...')
                view.entryconfigure('Show file name', label='Mostrar nome do arquivo')

            if lan=='Español':
                bar.entryconfigure('Archivo', label='Arquivo')
                bar.entryconfigure('Vista', label='Exibir')
                bar.entryconfigure('Ayuda', label='Ajuda')
                file.entryconfigure('Nuevo', label='Novo')
                file.entryconfigure('Abrir Reciente', label='Abrir Recente')
                file.entryconfigure('Salir', label='Sair')
                view.entryconfigure('Mostrar nombre de archivo', label='Mostrar nome do arquivo')

            lan="Português"
            titleshow(s=False)
    if l=="Español":
        if lan!='Español':
            janela.title('Bloc de Notas')

            if lan=='English':
                bar.entryconfigure('File', label='Archivo')
                bar.entryconfigure('View', label='Vista')
                bar.entryconfigure('Help', label='Ayuda')
                file.entryconfigure('New', label='Nuevo')
                file.entryconfigure('Open', label='Abrir')
                file.entryconfigure('Open Recent', label='Abrir Reciente')
                file.entryconfigure('Save', label='Salvar')
                file.entryconfigure('Save as', label='Salvar como')
                file.entryconfigure('Quit', label='Salir')
                view.entryconfigure('Show file name', label='Mostrar nombre de archivo')
                view.entryconfigure('Language', label='Idioma')
                help.entryconfigure('About...', label='Sobre...')

            if lan=='Português':
                bar.entryconfigure('Arquivo', label='Archivo')
                bar.entryconfigure('Exibir', label='Vista')
                bar.entryconfigure('Ajuda', label='Ayuda')
                file.entryconfigure('Novo', label='Nuevo')
                file.entryconfigure('Abrir Recente', label='Abrir Reciente')
                file.entryconfigure('Sair', label='Salir')
                view.entryconfigure('Mostrar nome do arquivo', label='Mostrar nombre de archivo')

            lan="Español"
            titleshow(s=False)
```

All the bar menu is translated, but the labels in their menus don't,
and the error in the Title appears.

[IMAGE - A Print of my Notepad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hkAx.png)

[IMAGE - View Menu and Language Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNk50.png)

Searching, looks like '_io.TextIOWrapper' is a object for files, but these menus aren't file objects! what I'm doing wrong?

(please, be patient and polite)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] as opposed to some code.

Comment: This is way too much code for us to wade through. You can probably duplicate your problem with a dozen lines of code.

Comment: Oh, Sorry guys, well, every chunk of code is the same, but with different strings for entryconfigure.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, Sorry guys, well, every chunk of code is the same, but with different strings for entryconfigure.

First, starts with this:

```
if l=="English":[...]
if l=="Português":[...]
if l=="Español":[...]
```

and inside these pieces of code, there is this:

```
if lan!='Português':
    janela.title('Bloco de Notas')
```

Here, I make a condition to execute all this piece of code just when the Notepad isn't with the code to choose.

(the code don't is executed when Notepad is with the English language and you choose to change to English again for example)

and I also translate the Notepad title.

```
if l=="English":
    if lan!='English':
        janela.title('Notepad')
        file.entryconfigure('Abrir', label='Open')
        file.entryconfigure('Salvar', label='Save')
        file.entryconfigure('Salvar como', label='Save as')
        view.entryconfigure('Idioma', label='Language')
        help.entryconfigure('Sobre...', label='About...')
```

the only who is different from the other in the begining, is in the code to translate to English. Because some words are the same in Portuguese and Spanish, a condition isn't necessary, like the code below:

```
        if lan=='Español':
            bar.entryconfigure('Archivo', label='File')
            bar.entryconfigure('Vista', label='View')
            bar.entryconfigure('Ayuda', label='Help')
            file.entryconfigure('Nuevo', label='New')
            file.entryconfigure('Abrir Reciente', label='Open Recent')
            file.entryconfigure('Salir', label='Quit')
            view.entryconfigure('Mostrar nombre de archivo', label='Show file name')
```

if the current language is one of the others, a lot of ".entryconfigures" are executed to change the current text to the new text ( if you know a better and efficient way to do this, please tell me )

each piece of code have 2 of them, and finally the global variable for language is changed. ( these titleshow function is just a function I created to manage the file name in the title )

```
        lan="English"
        titleshow(s=False)
```

Check out a better view of one piece of code:

```
if l=="English":
    if lan!='English':
        janela.title('Notepad')
        file.entryconfigure('Abrir', label='Open')
        file.entryconfigure('Salvar', label='Save')
        file.entryconfigure('Salvar como', label='Save as')
        view.entryconfigure('Idioma', label='Language')
        help.entryconfigure('Sobre...', label='About...')

        if lan=='Português':
            bar.entryconfigure('Arquivo', label='File')
            bar.entryconfigure('Exibir', label='View')
            bar.entryconfigure('Ajuda', label='Help')
            file.entryconfigure('Novo', label='New')
            file.entryconfigure('Abrir Recente', label='Open Recent')
            file.entryconfigure('Sair', label='Quit')
            view.entryconfigure('Mostrar nome do arquivo', label='Show file name')

        if lan=='Español':
            bar.entryconfigure('Archivo', label='File')
            bar.entryconfigure('Vista', label='View')
            bar.entryconfigure('Ayuda', label='Help')
            file.entryconfigure('Nuevo', label='New')
            file.entryconfigure('Abrir Reciente', label='Open Recent')
            file.entryconfigure('Salir', label='Quit')
            view.entryconfigure('Mostrar nombre de archivo', label='Show file name')

        lan="English"
        titleshow(s=False)
```

But, the cascade menus inside the bar menu aren't working...